# Flutter WebRTC Audio Issue in iOS

Tags: flutter, audio, webrtc, videocall, flutter-webrtc

Flutter WebRTC video call voice is not hearing in iPhone speaker
Getting UnimplementedError when I use _localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enableSpeakerphone(true);

I have using flutter_webrtc: ^0.9.24 package for video call. it's working fine in android devices. But some iOS devices not hearing sound, some iOS devices sound getting ear speaker only. I need to show sound on loud speaker.

Getting UnimplementedError when I use _localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enableSpeakerphone(true);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade flutter_webrtc to version flutter_webrtc: 0.9.22 to fix on/off loud speaker in IOS.